# Quadratic equations solver in java

Tags: java, quadratic

I tried and succeed to build a quadratic equation solver.

```
public class Solver {
public static void main (String[] args) {
int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
double positive = (-b + Math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2*a;
double negative = (-b - Math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2*a;
System.out.println("First answer is " + positive);
System.out.println("Second answer is " + negative);
} 
}
```

Sometimes I get NaN in the output.
What did i do wrong?

Comment: For what input values?

Comment: Well what inputs did you give? I suspect you gave values such that there *are* no solutions. (i.e. b^2 - 4ac is negative.)

Comment: You need to handle the cases of `a=0` and `b*b-4*a*c` is negative.

Comment: I would declare a, b and c as `double`, sometimes you can get integer / double aritmetic clash (especialy when you divide), but this doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: @Rona: works fine here: http://ideone.com/SV2GF8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quadratic Formula Program - getting NaN error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753021/quadratic-formula-program-getting-nan-error)

Comment: You need to put the denominator in parentheses: `x/2*a -> x/(2*a)`

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` - not a number - is a value, that represents the result of invalid mathematical operations. Using real numbers, you cannot compute a square root of negative number - so `NaN` is returned.

Another problem with your solution is `/2*a` fragment. Division and multiplication have equal priority, so parenthesis are necessary. Moreover, if `a` is equal to zero, Java will throw `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` - you need also to check it.

One possible solution will be:

```
if (a == 0) {
    System.out.println("Not a quadratic equation.");
    return;
}

double discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;
if (discriminant < 0) {
    System.out.println("Equation has no ansewer.");
} else {
    double positive = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
    double negative = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a);
    System.out.println("First answer is " + positive);
    System.out.println("Second answer is " + negative);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Did you ment the first double to be discriminant?

Comment: @Rona Yep, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

NaN stands for Not a Number. You have entered inputs that caused a mathematically undefined operation. so if the first number "a" is zero you will get that, and if b*b is greater than 4*a*c you will also get that message, the first situation is division by zero and the second is calculating the root of negative number.

Comment: How can I prevent Nan?